# Need Help Incorporating Tidyr's Spread into a Function that Outputs a List of Dataframes with Grouped Counts

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Using the sample data at the bottom, I want to find counts of the Gender and FP variables, then spread these variables using tidyr::spread(). I'm attempting to do this by creating a list of dataframes, one for the Gender counts, and one for FP counts. The reason I'm doing this is to eventually cbind both dataframes. However, I'm having trouble incorporating the tidyr::spread into my function.

The function below creates a list of two dataframes with counts for Gender and FP, but the counts are not "spread."

```
  group_by_quo=quos(Gender,FP)

 DF2<-map(group_by_quo,~DF%>%
    group_by(Code,!!.x)%>%
    summarise(n=n()))
```

If I add tidyr::spread, it doesn't work. I'm not sure how to incorporate this since each dataframe in the list has a different variable.

```
group_by_quo=quos(Gender,FP)

 DF2<-map(group_by_quo,~DF%>%
    group_by(Code,!!.x)%>%
    summarise(n=n()))%>%
    spread(!!.x,n)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Sample Code:

```
Subject<-c("Subject1","Subject2","Subject1","Subject3","Subject3","Subject4","Subject2","Subject1","Subject2","Subject4","Subject3","Subject4")
Code<-c("AAA","BBB","AAA","CCC","CCC","DDD","BBB","AAA","BBB","DDD","CCC","DDD")
Code2<-c("AAA2","BBB2","AAA2","CCC2","CCC2","DDD2","BBB2","AAA2","BBB2","DDD2","CCC2","DDD2")
Gender<-c("Male","Male","Female","Male","Female","Female","Female","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male")
FP<-c("F","P","P","P","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F")
DF<-data_frame(Subject,Code,Code2,Gender,FP)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misplaced the closing parenthesis. This code works for me:

```
library(tidyverse)

Subject<-c("Subject1","Subject2","Subject1","Subject3","Subject3","Subject4","Subject2","Subject1","Subject2","Subject4","Subject3","Subject4")
Code<-c("AAA","BBB","AAA","CCC","CCC","DDD","BBB","AAA","BBB","DDD","CCC","DDD")
Code2<-c("AAA2","BBB2","AAA2","CCC2","CCC2","DDD2","BBB2","AAA2","BBB2","DDD2","CCC2","DDD2")
Gender<-c("Male","Male","Female","Male","Female","Female","Female","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male")
FP<-c("F","P","P","P","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F")
DF<-data_frame(Subject,Code,Code2,Gender,FP)

group_by_quo <- quos(Gender, FP)

DF2 <- map(group_by_quo,
  ~DF %>%
    group_by(Code,!!.x) %>%
    summarise(n=n()) %>%
    spread(!!.x,n))
```

This last part is a bit more concise using `count`:

```
DF2 <- map(group_by_quo,
  ~DF %>%
    count(Code,!!.x) %>%
    spread(!!.x,n))
```

And by using `count` the unnecessary grouping information is removed as well.

Comment: Thanks, but when I try I get - "Error: Invalid Column Specification" - do you know what this error means? I only get the error when I incorporate the tidyr::spread component, otherwise it works...

Comment: You're saying that if you open a fresh R, copy-paste the above code snippet, the one I posted, you get an error? I don't, I get the result I expect. Can you try that?

Comment: Are you using the most recent version of Tidyr...the package that includes tidyeval? I may have an older tidyr. I'll check and try the code one more time...

Comment: I use tidyr version 0.8.0, there's no tidyeval.
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Comment: I was my Tidyr version. I installed the newest version and it worked. I think the newer Tidyr packages are compatible with tidyeval, so the older versions don't recognize the "!!" syntax? Anyways, there was this issue and the parenthesis issue. I'll go ahead and accept your answer...